# Get categories and subcategories as tree display

Tags: magento2

How do I get the Categories and the subcategories recursively using Magento 2? I was able to display all categories but the problem is I need to display it in a treelike manner such as below

- Default category

  - Home
  - About Us
  - Products

    - P-one

      - SC-Four
    - P-two

      - SC-One
      - SC-Two
    - Site Map
    - SC-One

But what I'm getting is the displaying of all of this category. Is there a way to achieve the above sample? Right now my code looks like this

```
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template 
{

protected $_categoryCollectionFactory;
protected $_categoryHelper;
protected $_categoryRepository;
protected $_storeManager;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $categoryCollectionFactory,
    array $data = []
)
{
    $this->_categoryCollectionFactory = $categoryCollectionFactory;
    $this->_categoryHelper = $categoryHelper;
    $this->_categoryCategoryRepository = $categoryRepository; 
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->layerResolver = $layerResolver;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

/**
 * Get category collection
 *
 * @param bool $isActive
 * @param bool|int $level
 * @param bool|string $sortBy
 * @param bool|int $pageSize
 * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection or array
 */
public function getCategoryCollection($isActive = true, $level = false, $sortBy = false, $pageSize = false)
{
    $collection = $this->_categoryCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');

    // Select only active categories
    if ($isActive) {
        $collection->addIsActiveFilter();
    }

    // select categories of certain level
    if ($level) {
        $collection->addLevelFilter($level);
    }

    // sort categories by some value
    if ($sortBy) {
        $collection->addOrderField($sortBy);
    }

    // select certain number of categories
    if ($pageSize) {
        $collection->setPageSize($pageSize);
    }

    return $collection;
}
```

and in my phtml file I have this

```
$categories = $this->getCategoryCollection();
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    echo $category->getName() . '<br />';
}
```

I'm not sure how to do about this and it would be great if I can also get a reference of any Magento 2 documentation where it teaches how to get different part of the site like the products and other stuff. Right now I have zero knowledge with Magento and I don't know any documentation/tutorial I can follow.

Would appreciate your help on this.

Answer (score 1):

`Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu` Block already give you all categories and sub categories recursively 
check the phtml file `/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/topmenu.phtml`
you can get menu with below code

```
<?php $columnsLimit = $block->getColumnsLimit() ?: 0; ?>
<?php echo $_menu = $block->getHtml('level-top', 'submenu', $columnsLimit) ?>
```

The above code will give you categories in  html tree structure.
you can also rewrite the block `Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu` to get output in  your required format.

OR

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$categoryFactory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category');
$all = $categoryFactory->getStoreCategories(false,true,true);
```

Comment: sorry for the noob question but where should I place this code above? in my phtml file? also if inside PHTML the line $block->getColumnLimit() shouldn't it be $this->getColumnsLimit()? sorry I don't know how to implement this

Comment: $this and $block are same thing

Comment: is there other way to retrieve the subcategories without having to retrieve the html part? Like perhaps I'll store the response into a multidimensional array

Comment: you have to rewrite the block class Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu

Comment: i also udpate my answer may be it help you

Comment: I have two store it only returns default store category